# Multilanguage login page based on url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, kotlin

I have locales as a part of url in my Spring Boot application:

```
/site - default locale

/en/site - English locale
```

I use custom interceptor for this:

```
    import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.LocaleEditor
    import org.springframework.util.Assert
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils

    import javax.servlet.ServletException
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
    import java.util.Locale
    import java.util.regex.Pattern

    class CustomLocaleChangeInterceptor : HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {

    private var localePattern: Pattern? = null

    private fun setLocalePattern(localePattern: String) {
        Assert.isTrue(localePattern.matches(".*\\(.*\\).*".toRegex()), "Your pattern needs to define a match group")
        this.localePattern = Pattern.compile(localePattern)
    }

    @Throws(ServletException::class)
    override fun preHandle(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?, handler: Any?): Boolean {

        this.setLocalePattern("(en)")

        val pathTranslated = request!!.requestURI.substring(request.contextPath.length)

        if (pathTranslated.isNotEmpty()) {
            val matcher = localePattern!!.matcher(pathTranslated)
            if (matcher.find()) {
                resolver(request, response, matcher.group(1))
            } else {
                resolver(request, response, "th")
            }
        }
        // Proceed in any case.
        return true

    }

    private fun resolver(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse?, locale: String) {
        val localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request) ?: throw IllegalStateException("No LocaleResolver found: not in a DispatcherServlet request?")
        val localeEditor = LocaleEditor()
        localeEditor.asText = locale
        localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, localeEditor.value as Locale)
    }
}
```

The question is what is the best way to handle two custom login pages in Spring? When restricted url contains /en user should be redirected to /en/login page (with English language) otherwise if page has default locale it should be redirect to /login url (with default language)

Answer (score 0):

in spiring security you can use this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class Securityhandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException  {
    Local local= LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    if(local.equals("yourcodeLang"){
       response.sendRedirect("/yourUrl");
    }
    else // your logic
    }
    }
```

and update  your config like this :

```
   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
              ....
              .successHandler(yourSuccessHandlerBean) // autowired or defined 
              ...
      }
```

Comment: Thank you Hicham but as I understand, your answer relates to where to redirect user after successful authentication. I need to do it in opposite way: to what login page send user to do their authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found this solution. Maybe is not perfect but it works.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
class SecurityConfigTH : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    private val localePattern: Pattern = Pattern.compile("^/en(\$|/)")

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .requestMatcher { !localePattern.matcher(it.requestURI.toString()).find() }
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
    }
}

@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
class SecurityConfigEN : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    private val localePattern: Pattern = Pattern.compile("^/en(\$|/)")

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .requestMatcher { localePattern.matcher(it.requestURI.toString()).find() }
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/en/login")
                    .permitAll()
    }
}
```